# How to avoid casting in java where we have the parent class object?

Tags: java, casting, java-17

Use case - 
I have a parent class and 2 children classes analogous to following

```
public class Parent {
    private Type type;
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private String someField;
    public Child1() {
        super(Type.One);
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    private String someOtherField;
    public Child2() {
        super(Type.Two);
    }
}
```

In the business logic, I have the parent class object and I want to access the children classes' variables based on the Type enum's value. Is there any other better & clear approach than casting with switch/visitor?
What I am using -

```
switch(parent.type){
    case Type.One:
        Child1 child = (Child1) parent;
        // logic
        break;
    case Type.Two:
        Child1 child = (Child1) parent;
        // logic
        break;
}
```

Disclaimer - We are using java 17 and I can't change it to java 17 preview to make use of switch with pattern matching.
Edit - Can't modify any of these classes.

Comment: It is not poissbile to change abstraction to invoke your login for both? e.g. add abstract method which will be implemented separately for each child class?

Comment: Can you ensure that there is no subclass other than `Child1` that also has `type == Type.ONE`?

Comment: @notAPPP It's not possible to modify any of these classes. Importing from an internal library

Comment: @Manfred yes we can endure that when type is One it's always Child1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use subclass-specific properties, you need to cast `parent` to the respective subclass. But I would do it in a safe way, as the language does not know about the additional constraint that `type == Type.ONE` corresponds to `Child1` and `type == Type.TWO` corresponds to `Child2`:

```java
if (parent instanceof Child1 child1) {
    // logic using child1
}
if (parent instanceof Child2 child2) {
    // logic using child2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields of the child classes have a similar structure, then you could make the parent class abstract and add abstract methods for the child classes to implement:

```java
public abstract class Parent {
    private Type type;

    protected abstract String getField();
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private String someField;
    public Child1() {
        super(Type.One);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getField() {
        return someField;
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    private String someOtherField;
    public Child2() {
        super(Type.Two);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getField() {
        return someOtherField;
    }
}
```

Then you don't need the `switch`. You can just write `parent.getField()` to access the fields.

If the fields do not have a similar structure, then you can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```java
public interface Visitor {
  void visit(Child1 child);

  void visit(Child2 child);
}

public abstract class Parent {
    private Type type;

    public abstract void accept(Visitor visitor);
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private String someField;
    public Child1() {
        super(Type.One);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    private String someOtherField;
    public Child2() {
        super(Type.Two);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

And use like so:

```java
parent.accept(new Visitor() {
  @Override
  public void visit(Child1 child) {
    // Child1 logic...
  }

  @Override
  public void visit(Child2 child) {
    // Child2 logic...
  }
});
```

Note that although the `accept` implementations in each child class look the same, they are actually different in behavior. The `Visitor` interface's `visit` method is overloaded so `visitor.visit(this)` will delegate to the overload associated with the current child class.

Lastly, with either one of these solutions, if you weren't using the `type` field for anything other than the `switch`, then you should be able to get rid of the `type` field.

EDIT: If you can't modify any of these classes, then there's no way to get around casting.

Comment: A comment above has clarified that _it is not possible to modify any of these classes._